# how to know the rendering length of a html label string

Tags: java, swing

I am using **html label** to display parameters and their values on **buttons**. Some buttons contain one parameter and some have 2 or 3 parameters. **" / "** is used to separate values. There is an empty line between the name and value. But in the cases of long values, I want to use that empty line to display the value like the "**Table H/V**" button.

I am trying to use the length of the value string to determine that empty line is needed or not. It doesn't work properly because the character number doesn't reflect the drawing length of that string. The button size is fixed.

I am asking **how can I know when I should have one more "< br>" which represent that empty line?** Or **how can I know when the value string will be wrapped to another line?**

This is my code:

```
 private static String getBtnDisplayStr(String name, String value)
    {
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        sBuilder.append("<html><center><b>");
        sBuilder.append(name);
        if(value.length() <= 12)  //add one empty line for short value string
        {
            sBuilder.append("</center></b><br><br><font size=\"2\">");
        }
        else
        {
            sBuilder.append("</center></b><br><font size=\"2\">");
        }
        sBuilder.append(value);
        sBuilder.append("</font></html>");

        return sBuilder.toString();
    }
```

here is the buttons:
[image]

Comment: SwingUtilities#layoutCompoundLabel

Answer (score 3):

- by default there no reason to calculating `PreferredSize` for `Html <=3.2` and `Swing JComponents`
- leave that for `LayoutManager`, for example GridLayout calculating screen size from the largest element

[image]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class HtmlAndJButton {

    final String buttonText = " Whatever words, <br> but nothing wise";
    final String buttonText1 = " Whatever words, <br> but nothing wise, "
            + "<br> plus 1st. line, ";
    final String buttonText2 = " Whatever words, <br> but nothing wise, "
            + "<br> plus 1st. line, <br> plus 2nd. line,";
    private JButton btn1 = new JButton("Toggle");
    private JButton button = new JButton(buttonText);
    private JButton button1 = new JButton("Toggle");
    private JButton button2 = new JButton("Toggle");

    public HtmlAndJButton() {
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                button.setText("<html><font color=" + (button.isEnabled()
                        ? "blue" : "red") + ">" + buttonText + "</font></html>");
                button.setEnabled(!button.isEnabled());
                button1.setText("<html><font color=" + (button1.isEnabled()
                        ? "red" : "green") + ">" + buttonText1 + "</font></html>");
                button1.setEnabled(!button1.isEnabled());
                button2.setText("<html><font color=" + (button2.isEnabled()
                        ? "green" : "yellow") + ">" + buttonText2 + "</font></html>");
                button2.setEnabled(!button2.isEnabled());
            }
        });
        button.setText("<html><font color=red>" + buttonText + "</font></html>");
        button1.setText("<html><font color=green>" + buttonText1 + "</font></html>");
        button2.setText("<html><font color=yellow>" + buttonText2 + "</font></html>");
        JFrame f = new JFrame("ButtonTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        f.add(button);
        f.add(button1);
        f.add(button2);
        f.add(btn1);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                HtmlAndJButton t = new HtmlAndJButton();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the text on the button, then examine the "preferred width" of the button.  If it is too great, adjust the text accordingly.

Here is an example with two of your buttons from above:

```
private static int BUTTON_WIDTH = 90;  // Adjust this as necessary

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

    JButton btn1 = new JButton(getBtnDisplayStr("Table H/V",null,"909.0 / 500.0"));
    if (btn1.getPreferredSize().width > BUTTON_WIDTH) {
        btn1.setText(getBtnDisplayStr("Table H/V", "909.0 /", "500.0"));
    }
    JButton btn2 = new JButton(getBtnDisplayStr("Acq/ISD",null,"1 / 1"));
    if (btn2.getPreferredSize().width > BUTTON_WIDTH) {
        btn2.setText(getBtnDisplayStr("Acq/ISD","1 /","1"));
    }

    pnl.add(btn1,BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    pnl.add(btn2,BorderLayout.LINE_END);

    frame.add(pnl);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static String getBtnDisplayStr(String name, String valueLine1, String valueLine2) {
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    sBuilder.append("<html><center><b>");
    sBuilder.append(name);
    sBuilder.append("</b><br/>");
    if (valueLine1 != null) {
        sBuilder.append("<font size=\"2\">");
        sBuilder.append(valueLine1);
        sBuilder.append("</font>");
    }
    sBuilder.append("<br/>");
    if (valueLine2 != null) {
        sBuilder.append("<font size=\"2\">");
        sBuilder.append(valueLine2);
        sBuilder.append("</font>");
    }
    sBuilder.append("<br/>");

    sBuilder.append("</center></html>");

    return sBuilder.toString();
}
```